# Why won't my python scripts run without the python command when moved from Windows to Linux?

Tags: command-line, python, executable, shebang

I have some Python files that I wrote on my Windows PC and then sent over to a Linux machine using pscp. They work as intended on Windows, but when I try to execute them on the Linux machine, I always get an error message.

I use the following process to run the code after importing the file "test.py":

First, I add the shebang line at the top of test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# rest of code
```

Then I modify permissions and try to run the script:

```
chmod +x test.py
./test.py
```

which gives me the error message

```
./test.py: Command not found.
```

If I create a file from scratch on the Linux machine and type in the exact same program text, the program will run just fine. Also, if I type the following code, the program runs just fine:

```
python test.py
```

Can anyone explain what is happening here? Thanks.

Comment: If you're coding on windows, your files may well have windows line endings. Then the shebang line would be `#!/usr/bin/python\r` and that command cannot be found. Try `dos2unix`

Comment: Used dos2unix, it worked perfectly. Thanks glenn jackman.